# ¿Cómo optimizar una función recursiva?

Tags: c, recursión

Un día, navegando por internet vi un artículo acerca de como optimizar la recursividad utilizando una criba que almacene los valores de los pasos que ya esten creados evitar crear todas las ramas del árbol binario que genera esta; ahorrando así recursos,memoria y energía.

Sin embargo, no logro encontrar como hacerlo ni me surgen ideas...

```
int main(){
    int n,i;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("%d\n",fibonacci(i));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
int fibonacci(int n){
    if((n==0)||(n==1)){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return(fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hay una técnica llamada "memoization" que se aplica a funciones idempotentes (que siempre dan el mismo valor para la misma entrada), no sólo a las recursivas. En ésta, la función primero revisa si ya hizo el cálculo para la variable recibida; en ese caso devuelve el valor previamente computado y almacenado por la misma función en una estructura interna. Si no, hace el cálculo, guarda el resultado internamente y lo devuelve al llamante. La estructura interna generalmente es un diccionario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La optimización que conozco de la recursividad recibe el nombre de "*Tail call optimization*", optimización de la llamada de cola.

Consiste en redactar la función recursiva de una manera determinada que ayuda al compilador a evitar alojar espacio de pila por cada llamada:

- La función recursiva sólo tiene una llamada recursiva.
- La recursión es lo último que hace la función en cada rama de ejecución.

Tal y como tienes redactada tu función, no se puede aprovechar de la optimización de llamada de cola ya que tiene dos llamadas recursivas:

```
int fibonacci(int n){
    if((n==0)||(n==1)){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return(fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2));
//             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
//              recursión 1    recursión 2
    }
}
```

Si modificas la función para que reciba los términos anteriores por parámetro, podrás sacar provecho de esta optmización:

```
int fibonacci(int n, int val = 1, int prev = 0)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return prev;

    return fibonacci(n - 1, val + prev, val);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

puedes hacerlo creando un `dictionary` que utilizaras como memoria para no volver a repetir las operaciones ya hechas!.

```
Dictionary<int, int> dict = new Dictionary<int, int>();

int fibonacci(int n){
    int value;

    if(dict.ContainsKey(n)) { return dict[n]}

    if((n==0)||(n==1)){
        value = 1;
    }
    else if( n ==2 ){
        value = 1;
    }

    else if(n>2){
        value = (fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2));
    }

    dict.Add(n, value);
    return value;
}
```